# Laravel Managing File Path

Tags: laravel, file, path

In my application users can upload files. In my controller I have the following:

```
//...
 $request->file->storeAs('/public/user_files',$fileName);
```

I don't like how I have to hard code the path `/public/user_files`, what is the proper way to manage file paths? I could simply create a variable but is there any better ways for maximum maintainability?

From my understanding I have a few options:

1. Create a variable
2. Create a new file in `config` directory that manages the path
3. Create a disk in `filesystem.php` and use `storeAs` with the custom disk

What is the best way to handle paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, you should use filesystem disks as you specified in your last option, it allows a centralized flexibility.

In this case, you may use Laravel helpers such as `public_path` or `storage_path`, for example:

```php
$request->file->storeAs(
    storage_path('app/public'), $fileName
);
```

Combined to a symbolic link, it allows flexibility about public assets.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#the-public-disk

Comment: Thanks, I went with the Disk option and it's going to make my code much more maintainable, very elegant solution! Also one thing to note on your answer is that `storeAs` by default points to the `storage/app` directory, so doesn't that make `storage_path` redundant?

Comment: Yeah it is probably, I did not know its default path.

Answer (score 0):

you can use helpper `public_path()`

```
$request->file->storeAs( public_path('/user_files') ,$fileName);
```

doc: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-public-path